# SQL Server left join not giving correct result

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, left-join

Good Day,

i have read some of the other problems people are facing with left joins, not giving correct result and maybe i am not understanding all the answers that well.

here is the problem i am having on my query

```
    SELECT 
       TA.column1
      ,D.column2
      ,D.column3
      ,TA.column4
      ,MI.[column5]
      ,MI.[column6]
      ,D.[column7]
      ,D.[column8]
      ,TA.[column9]
      ,TA.[column10]
      ,UC.[column11]
      ,UC.[column12]
      ,TA.[column13]
      ,TA.[column14]
      ,TA.[column15]
      ,TA.[column16]
      ,TA.[column17]
      ,'0' AS column18
      ,TA.[column19]
      ,'12.2' AS column20
      ,'None' AS column21
      ,'0' AS column22
      ,'1' AS column23
      ,TA.[column24]
      ,'0' AS column25
      ,'0' AS column26
      ,LD.column27
  FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table1] AS TA WITH (NOLOCK)
  FULL OUTER JOIN 
  [DB].[dbo].[Table2] AS LD WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON
  TA.[coulmn1]=LD.[coulmn5]
  INNER JOIN
  [DB].[dbo].[Table3] AS MI WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON
  TA.coulmn10 = MI.[coulmn3]
  LEFT JOIN
  [DB].[dbo].[Table4] AS D WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON
  TA.coulmn25 = D.coulmn1
  INNER JOIN
  [DB1].[dbo].[Table5] AS UC WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON
  TA.coulmn12 = UC.coulmn3

  WHERE  
  (LD.coulmn5 != TA.[coulmn1])
  AND
  (TA.[coulmn23]= '0')
```

the problem is when i update the query and remove

```
FULL OUTER JOIN 
  [DB].[dbo].[Table2] AS LD WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON
  TA.[coulmn1]=LD.[coulmn5]
```

as well as remove the following where clause:

> ```
>   WHERE  
>   (LD.coulmn5 != TA.[coulmn1])
>   AND
> ```

i have 3 results in my view on the right table. this is correct as the one result has not been written into the left table

when i put back the left outer join and where clause i only see 2 results again, should there not be three results with the last column `,LD.column27` showing as `NULL`.
this column is to accept `NOT NULL` could this be a reason i am not getting the prefered result?

Comment: In query,you should use all left Joins only after All Inner joins for correct Result, other wise all Inner join which are used before Left join will be trated as Left Join only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `FULL OUTER JOIN` and remove  `WHERE  (LD.coulmn5 != TA.coulmn1]) AND' part

Try this:

```
SELECT 
       TA.column1
      ,D.column2
      ,D.column3
      ,TA.column4
      ,MI.[column5]
      ,MI.[column6]
      ,D.[column7]
      ,D.[column8]
      ,TA.[column9]
      ,TA.[column10]
      ,UC.[column11]
      ,UC.[column12]
      ,TA.[column13]
      ,TA.[column14]
      ,TA.[column15]
      ,TA.[column16]
      ,TA.[column17]
      ,'0' AS column18
      ,TA.[column19]
      ,'12.2' AS column20
      ,'None' AS column21
      ,'0' AS column22
      ,'1' AS column23
      ,TA.[column24]
      ,'0' AS column25
      ,'0' AS column26
      ,LD.column27
  FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table1] AS TA WITH (NOLOCK)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [DB].[dbo].[Table2] AS LD WITH (NOLOCK) ON  TA.[coulmn1]=LD.[coulmn5]
  INNER JOIN  [DB].[dbo].[Table3] AS MI WITH (NOLOCK)  ON  TA.coulmn10 = MI.[coulmn3]
  LEFT JOIN  [DB].[dbo].[Table4] AS D WITH (NOLOCK)  ON  TA.coulmn25 = D.coulmn1
  INNER JOIN  [DB1].[dbo].[Table5] AS UC WITH (NOLOCK)  ON  TA.coulmn12 = UC.coulmn3
  WHERE   (TA.[coulmn23]= '0')
```

Comment: No Still the same only seeing the results where there is data in both tables

Comment: @user3676496 Can you explain with sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Should work:

```
SELECT 
   TA.column1
  ,D.column2
  ,D.column3
  ,TA.column4
  ,MI.[column5]
  ,MI.[column6]
  ,D.[column7]
  ,D.[column8]
  ,TA.[column9]
  ,TA.[column10]
  ,UC.[column11]
  ,UC.[column12]
  ,TA.[column13]
  ,TA.[column14]
  ,TA.[column15]
  ,TA.[column16]
  ,TA.[column17]
  ,'0' AS column18
  ,TA.[column19]
  ,'12.2' AS column20
  ,'None' AS column21
  ,'0' AS column22
  ,'1' AS column23
  ,TA.[column24]
  ,'0' AS column25
  ,'0' AS column26
  ,LD.column27
 FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table1] AS TA WITH (NOLOCK)
 FULL OUTER JOIN 
  [DB].[dbo].[Table2] AS LD WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON
 TA.[coulmn1]=LD.[coulmn5]
 INNER JOIN
 [DB].[dbo].[Table3] AS MI WITH (NOLOCK)
ON
TA.coulmn10 = MI.[coulmn3]
LEFT JOIN
[DB].[dbo].[Table4] AS D WITH (NOLOCK)
ON
TA.coulmn25 = D.coulmn1
INNER JOIN
[DB1].[dbo].[Table5] AS UC WITH (NOLOCK)
ON
TA.coulmn12 = UC.coulmn3

WHERE  
(LD.coulmn5 is null)
AND
(TA.[coulmn23]= '0')
```

Comment: I found the problem on the query why it is not working correctly, as soon as i remove
  INNER JOIN
  [DB1].[dbo].[Table5] AS UC WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON
  TA.coulmn12 = UC.coulmn3
then the data is there when i add it again i get no result back can it be because i am joining a different DB to my query?

Comment: This is because of the nature of your data. Try changing inner join for a left join for Table5 and see what happens.

Comment: It is working now it is a mixture of the answers provided by Dmitry and Saharsh after i got the DB2 connection not giving me results i removed the "WHERE (LD.coulmn5 is null)" only left "WHERE (TA.[coulmn23]= '0')" now the data is displaying correctly Thank You both for the Help.